# Roomba s9 -- no communication

Tags: serial, roomba

I connected my Roomba s9+ USB port to my Windows 10 PC, which cannot detect it (nothing under Ports):

[image]

I messed around a bit and updated drivers, and now Windows 10 detects Roomba as:

[image: Windows 10 device detection]

I don't know what to do with this. Putty serial connection to this port receives nothing.

What should I do to troubleshoot the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Roomba S9+ doesn't support the [Open Interface spec](https://edu.irobot.com/learning-library/create-2-oi-spec).  So you can't control the robot through the USB port. And neither do any of the other latest generation of Roombas (i.e. the "i", and "j" series)

Only certain models of the 500, 600, 700, 800, and maybe "e" series robots have the serial port hardware and code support to make it "hackable". (And the existence of the port doesn't mean that the code supports it).  This feature was phased out a while ago.  So the older the robot, the more likely it will be to support the OI spec.

The proper way to control a Roomba is to use a "Create".  i.e. either a Create (antique), Create2 (recently retired), or [Create3](https://edu.irobot.com/what-we-offer/create3).

*Disclaimer: I work at iRobot where I am developing the next generation of consumer robots. However, my postings on this site are my own and don't necessarily represent iRobot's positions, strategies, or opinions.*

Comment: cool, thank you!